# How do I group data based on a single variable in SPSS?

Tags: spss

I have a large dataset with each data representing  individuals. Now I need to know the average of outcome occurrences per family. I have IDs for each family  and each family has a different family size. In answering the above I would like to group data into different families.

Comment: You could do a split-file by family ID and run descriptive statistics on your variables.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica  If this is off topic for stats, where on SE would this be on topic?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to get these means as an output table is [SPSS' MEANS command](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-means-command/).

If, instead, you'd like to have the means per familiy as a dataset, try [AGGREGATE](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-aggregate-command/).